# How to Differentiate the equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I am a high school student and stuck in understanding how to solve this problem:

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $e^x + e^y = e^{x+y}$.

Please let me know how to approach solving the question as I've tried a lot and still can't solve it

Below is the steps I have tried
$$
    =\int(e^x + e^y) dx
    =\int e^x dx + \int e^y dx
    =e^x \int dx + e^y \int dx
    =e^x . x  + e^y . x
    =x (e^y + e^x)
$$
I am not sure after this.

Comment: Are you trying to integrate or differentiate? Your title and your question suggest different problems. Also, here's a helpful guide to MathJax formatting :) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I have added my analysis in the question

Comment: If "Find $\frac{dx}{dy}$ if $e^x+e^y=e^{x+y}$" is the way the problem is really stated, you would need to differentiate, not integrate; there are a couple helpful answers showing how you would go about doing that

Comment: Oh thanks I am sorry for the mistake

Comment: You should be using [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) by now.

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$e^x=e^y(e^x-1)$$ or
$$e^y=\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}$$ or
$$y=x-\ln(e^x-1).$$
Thus, $$y'=1-\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}=\frac{1}{1-e^x}.$$

Answer (score 3):

This is easy if you know [implicit differentiation](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html).

We have: $$\frac{d}{dx}[e^x + e^y] = \frac{d}{dx}[e^{x+y}]$$ $$ \implies e^x + e^y y’ = e^{x+y}\frac{d}{dx}[x+y]$$ $$\implies e^x + e^y y’ = e^{x+y}[1+y’]$$ $$\implies y’[e^{x+y}-e^y]=e^x - e^{x+y}$$ $$\implies y’ = \, ??$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\implies e^{-x}+e^{-y}=1$$

Now differentiate $$-e^{-x}-e^{-y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0\iff\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^{y-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Upon dividing  $e^x + e^y= e^{x+y}$ by $e^{x+y}$ we get $e^{-y} + e^{-x} =1$.

Differentiate both sides leads to $-y'e^{-y} - e^{-x} = 0$. Substituting $1-e^{-x}$ for $e^{-y}$ we get $-y'(1-e^{-x}) = e^{-x}$. Solve for $y'$ and the result is $y' = \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}-1}$. Multiply top and bottom  by $e^x$ to get $y'=\frac 1{1-e^x}$.

Comment: Hey Mohammad Riazi-Kermani always use https://goo.gl/OWv9nr to format your answer so that it becomes readable